# Do there exist equations that cannot be solved in $\mathbb{C}$, but can be solved in $\mathbb{H}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

Excluding polynomials (whose solutions are covered by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), do there exist any univariable equations that cannot be solved in the complex numbers, but **can** be solved other fields, such as the quaternions, octonions, etc.?

I know that not all equations can be solved (in any field), such as $e^w=0,$ or $0x=0$ (no unique solution), and also that some equations that **can** be solved in $\mathbb{C}$ can also be solved in $\mathbb{H}$, but with many more solutions (e.g. $w^2+1=0$), but I'm wondering whether there exist equations that can **only** be solved in higher-dimensional division algebras (than $\mathbb{C}$)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a division algebra instead of "higher dimensional fields"? $\mathbb{H}$ is not commutative.

Comment: Oh, yes! So I suppose I should remove sedenions from this list, then. So just $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$.

Comment: $(\textrm{i} \, x-x\, \textrm{i})^2+1=0$

Comment: Ah. I was wondering why Bombyx mentioned that $\mathbb{H}$ is not commutative. But it makes sense in this case, that this equation couldn't be solved in $\mathbb{C}$. Thanks!

Comment: @WimC By the way, how would one go about solving your equation analytically?

Comment: @alexqwx If you can't think of a more clever way, you can always expand $x$ into $a+bi+cj+dk$ and multiply. Hastily doing some computations, I think I found that anything with $c^2+d^2=\frac14$ would do the trick.

Comment: Dear @alexqwx : might I say it looks like you picked a rather odd requirement on equations? First, it looks like you're willing to use almost any elementary functions in equations (such as $e^w=0$). Then you you mention something about wanting unique solutions, but $e^w=i$ does not have unique solutions in $\Bbb C $, and for that matter $x^2-1=0$ does not have unique solutions in $\Bbb R$. Really, the most natural equations to look at are the ones which only make use of multiplication and addition: polynomials (variables not necessarily commuting with coefficients). WimC's example is great :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$(\textrm{i} \, x - x \, \textrm{i})^2+1=0$